# How do I export a function in a class component into another page?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, function, react-redux, components

I want to change the text of a message in (Message.js) from 'Not Updated' to 'Updated' when a button on another page (PageButton.js) has been clicked.

Message.js

```
import React from 'react';
class Message extends React.Component {

    constructor (){
       super()
       this.state = {
           message: 'Not Updated'
        }
    }

    changeMessage(){
        this.setState =({
            message: 'Updated'
        }
        )
    }

  render(){
    return (
      <h1>{this.state.message}</h1>
      )
    }
  }

export default Message
```

Pagebutton.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { changeMessage } from "./Message"; //this does not work
import Message from "./Message"; //this does not work too

class Pagebutton extends React.Component {

    render(){

        return (
           <div>
               <button onClick={()=>this.changeMessage()}>Change Text</button>

           </div>
           
        )
    }
}

export default Pagebutton;
```

In Pagebutton.js, 'changeMessage' is not defined, how do I make it work? If this way of importing functions is not correct, please teach me an alternative way of doing it :)

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can't export things inside functions or classes in javascript. In order to get access, you'd have to pass down `changeMessage` as a `prop` from a component that both `Message` and `Pagebutton` are descendants of. See: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

An example setup would be:

Container.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Pagebutton from "./Pagebutton";
import Message from "./Message";

class Container extends React.Component {

    constructor (){
       super()
       this.state = {
           message: 'Not Updated'
        }
    }

    changeMessage(){
        this.setState =({
            message: 'Updated'
        }
        )
    }

  render(){
    return (
      <Message message={this.state.message} />
      <Pagebutton changeMessage={this.changeMessage.bind(this)} /> 
      )
    }
  }

export default Container
```

Pagebutton.js

```
import React from 'react';

class Pagebutton extends React.Component {

    render(){

        return (
           <div>
               <button onClick={()=>this.props.changeMessage()}>Change Text</button>

           </div>
           
        )
    }
}

export default Pagebutton;
```

Message.js

```
import React from 'react';
class Message extends React.Component {


  render(){
    return (
      <h1>{this.props.message}</h1>
      )
    }
  }

export default Message
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your response and explanation. I don't think that works because I want the message to be on one page called Message.js and the button to be on another page called Pagebutton.js. In the example you have given, Container.js has both Message and Pagebutton. However, I don't want them to be together on the same page. Is there another way to do so? Am I taking this the right way or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: You can have any number of components between my example Container and the two components you want each state/method to be used in. I.e. even if it's the component that you call `ReactDOM.render()` on, the respective prop would be passed down through each component until it reaches `Message` or `Pagebutton` Components. You can have React decide which page to render with React Router, or by using simple conditionals `{if x ? (<OneComponent />) : (<Another Component />)}`.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to answer by @Kyruski, you can also use Context API, which enables "magically passing props".

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Documentation has many examples, that you can try.